# Maven - package not including content of webapp

Tags: maven

I'm building war (with mvn package, after I use mvn compile) but for some reason it only puts META-INF and WEB-INF in my war. It doesn't include files from webapp. What could be the problem?

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>some-name</groupId>
  <artifactId>some-name</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>some-name</name>
  <description>name</description>
   <dependencies> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>javax.activation</groupId> 
       <artifactId>activation</artifactId> 
       <version>1.1.1</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.3.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId> 
       <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId> 
       <version>1.1</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>2.2.8</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>javax.inject</groupId> 
       <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId> 
       <version>1</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>javax.jws</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0-MR1</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId> 
       <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId> 
       <version>1.5.1</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.management.j2ee</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.1.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId> 
       <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.resource</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.rmi</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.4.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.auth.message</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-jaspi-api_1.1_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.jacc</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-jacc-api_1.5_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jsp</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-jsp-api_2.3_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.1.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jstl</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.1.2.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>javax.validation</groupId> 
       <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId> 
       <version>1.1.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId> 
       <version>3.0.10.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId> 
       <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId> 
       <version>1.6.3</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.4.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.rpc</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.1.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.soap</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.3.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.ws</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>2.0.2.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
       <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId> 
       <version>5.1.3.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId> 
       <artifactId>picketbox</artifactId> 
       <version>4.0.21.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId> 
       <artifactId>picketbox-commons</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.0.final</version> 
     </dependency> 

     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId> 
       <artifactId>wildfly-controller-client</artifactId> 
       <version>8.2.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-dmr</artifactId> 
       <version>1.2.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId> 
       <version>3.1.4.GA</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId> 
       <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId> 
       <version>3.0.10.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId> 
       <artifactId>async-http-servlet-3.0</artifactId> 
       <version>3.0.10.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId> 
       <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId> 
       <version>3.0.10.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId> 
       <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId> 
       <version>3.0.10.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId> 
       <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId> 
       <version>3.0.10.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId> 
       <version>2.1.0</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.batch</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-batch-api_1.0_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.enterprise.concurrent</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-concurrency-api_1.0_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.websocket</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec</artifactId> 
       <version>1.1.0.Final</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId> 
       <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId> 
       <version>1.0.3</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
       <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
       <version>2.3.1</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies> 
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
         <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I tried googling for the problem, I tried all the solutions, but none worked.

Thanks,
K

Comment: Remove the entries `<sourceDirectory>...</sourceDirectory>` cause it does not make sense. Follow the conventions. Why have you added the `src/main/webapp` folder as resource? Which looks wrong as well...and why are you using not an uptodate version of [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/).

Comment: @khmarbaise I already removed <sourceDirectory>, didn't help. about adding webapp to resource I read it might help, it wasn't there at start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to remove WebContent configuration in maven-war-plugin.
And it works.